# Having trouble creating an struct inside a class inside a function

Tags: c++, class, object, struct

Receiving the error "the default constructor of "Library::Transaction" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

the error occurs on line 129 in the file that defines functions

here is my header file "classes.h"

```
https://pastebin.com/94BBGF4U

#pragma once
class Library {
    vector<Book> books;
    vector<Patron> people;

public:
    struct Transaction {
        Book book;
        Patron theMan;
        Date chapDate;
    };

    vector<Transaction> transactions;

    void add_Books_Lib(const Book& a) { books.push_back(a); }
    void add_Patron_Lib(const Patron& a) { people.push_back(a); }
    void check_Out(Patron & person, Book& a);
    bool check_User(Patron& person);
    bool check_Book(Book& a);
};
```

here is my cpp file that defines functions

```
https://pastebin.com/gEF5s5Yc

#include "classes.h"
    void Library::check_Out(Patron& person, Book& a){
        if (check_Book(a) && check_User(person)) {
            if (!person.check_If_Owes_Fee()) {
                a.checkOut();
                Transaction person.get_Patron_Name(); //error here
            }
            else cout << "Can't perform operation.  User owes a fee";
        }
        else cout << "Invalid, user or book not in library";
        }
```

here is the main cpp if it means anything

https://pastebin.com/hT0UmcVT

```
#include "classes.h"

int main() {
    Book one("123H", "Hey", "Cool", Date(31, 12, 2020), Genre::FICTION);
    Book two("123H", "Hey", "Cool", Date(31, 12, 2020), Genre::CHILDREN);

    operator<<(cout, one);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add all relevant code directly to the question.

Comment: I would imagine (without looking at the code) that you're implicitly using the default Transaction constructor when no such constructor exists. Please put the relavent code in the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them, like for example include a [mcve] of your code, as well as a full and complete copy-paste (as text!) of the actual errors you get, with comments in the code where you get them.

Comment: added relevant code

Comment: This line `Transaction person.get_Patron_Name();` doesn't make sense. Can you explain what you want to do here?

Comment: that function returns a string that is the name of the patron..i've also tried "Transaction one;" which didn't work as well,  i'm simply trying to create an object Transaction

Comment: What error do you get when you tried `Transaction one;`?

Comment: The first version simply makes no sense. I can't advise you how to fix it because I don't know what you intended. However the second version `Transaction one;` does at least make sense, but it doesn't compile because `Transaction` does not have a default constructor. And (sneaking a look at the rest of your code) it doesn't have one because `Book` does not have a default constructor.

Comment: `Transaction person;` defines a new variable with the name `person` (which is distinct from, and unrelated to, the argument `person`). `person.get_Patron_Name();` calls the `get_Patron_Name` member function on the `person` object, and then discards the result. But `Transaction person.get_Patron_Name();` just is nonsensical and is syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

your structure `struct Transaction` doesn't contain the default constructor. Why? Normally, if your structure doesn't contain any constructor, the compiler adds it itself if all fields of the structure can be initialized using corresponding default constructors. However, the structure `Book` doesn't have a default constructor but have a non-default constructor. Therefore, compiler won't add a default constructor to `Book`. So, neither for Transaction.

So, either you explicitly define a default constructor (without arguments) to `Transaction` and cars about `.book` field there. Or you define a default constructor for `Book`.

Answer (score 0):

`Transaction` won't receive the automatically generated default constructor unless all of `Book`, `Patron`, and `Date` have accessible default constructors.

For what it's worth, you might not be able to use some of the methods in `std::vector` if the `Book` and `Patron` classes don't have default constructors either.